# Selecting Parent Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has a tree structure that has no limit to the number of levels it has. Each level has a tick box I need to be able to allow users to tick which levels they are interested in. If a user clicks on a level then all of the parent levels for that child need to be selected. Also if the parent check box is unticked then all child levels should be unticked.

I tried writing the code below which kind of works however if I click the child it will tick the parent and grandparent but leave the child unselected. I am also unable to unselect items as every-time I select a box it always selects it again.

I keep trying to make changes to the code and have ideas but I think I am going down the wrong direction and wanted to know if there are better solutions available for what I am trying to achieve. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Check Box</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".test").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });

            function set_checked(id, checked) {
                $("#ID_" + id).attr("checked", checked)
                alert(id);
            }

            function CheckMe(id) {
                var IDS = id.replace("ID_", "");
                var IDS = IDS.split('_');
                for (i = 0; i < IDS.length; i++) {
                    set_checked(IDS[i], true);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <p>
                    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" id="ID_123" value="123" onClick="CheckMe('ID_123')" class="test">Grandparent
                    <br>
                    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" id="ID_124" value="124" onClick="CheckMe('ID_123_124')"class="test">Parent
                    <br>
                    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" id="ID_125" value="125" onClick="CheckMe('ID_123_124_125')"class="test">Child
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used jQuery `PreventDefault` to stop the default actions of the checkbox. I would be most grateful for any direction with this.

Edit:

Here are the options within an unordered list. My example above was misleading as it only had three options as I was trying to test clicking the bottom option and having the parent options clicked without considering that there would be multiple trees.

```
<form action="" method="get" id="test">
<ul>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="1">
<label>Level 1</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="2"><label>Level 1.1</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="3"><label>Level 1.1.1</label>
</ul>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="4"><label>Level 1.2</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="5"><label>Level 1.2.1</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="6"><label>Level 1.2.2</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="7"><label>Level 1.2.3</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="8"><label>Level 1.2.3.1</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="9"><label>Level 1.2.3.2</label>
</ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="10"><label>Level 1.2.4</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="11"><label>Level 1.2.5</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="12"><label>Level 1.2.6</label>
</ul>
</ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="13"><label>Level 2</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="14"><label>Level 2.1</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="15"><label>Level 2.1.1</label>
</ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="16"><label>Level 2.2</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="16"><label>Level 2.2.1</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="17"><label>Level 2.2.2</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="18"><label>Level 2.2.3</label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="19"><label>Level 2.2.3.1</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="20"><label>Level 2.2.3.2</label>
</ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="21"><label>Level 2.2.4</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="22"><label>Level 2.2.5</label>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="23"><label>Level 2.2.6</label>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You may want to consider nested `<ul>`s for structuring your check box hierarchy, it will allow easier manipulation and presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Check Box</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".test").on('click',function () {
                    var clicked = $(this);
                    var hermanos = clicked.siblings(".test");
                    if(clicked.attr("checked")=="checked")
                        $.each(hermanos, function(index,object){
                            if($(object).val() < clicked.val())
                                    $(object).attr("checked", "checked");

                    });
                else
                    $.each(hermanos, function(index,object){
                        if($(object).val() > clicked.val())
                                $(object).removeAttr("checked");

                    });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <p>
                <input name="ID" type="checkbox" value="123"  class="test">Grandparent
                <br>
                <input name="ID" type="checkbox"  value="124" class="test">Parent
                <br>
                <input name="ID" type="checkbox"  value="125" class="test">Child
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The code example I used was misleading. The are many branches within the trees and there could be multiple "families".

Answer (score 4):

There are plugins that already provide this functionality.

Try this, as it does exactly what you are looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

demo:

http://checkboxtree.googlecode.com/svn/tags/checkboxtree-0.5.2/index.html

Comment: +1 jquery is great and does all thing. it is good too, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "levels", are the checkboxes nested inside other elements, or are they as in your example, just siblings ?

If the example HTML is correct, remove all your inline JS, and just do this :

```
$(".test").on('change', function() {
    var i = $(this).index(),
        c = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(".test").filter(function() { return $(this).index() < i; }).prop('checked', c);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tM9RN/)